# How to perform Preview in CKEditor

Tags: ckeditor

I am using CKEditor to get HTML from the user. The user will use HTML tags and it will be saved in the database. I need a functionality for the user to see how the page will be displayed when open as .html before saving in the database.

Is it possible to do that using CKEditor and if yes.....then how?

Thanks-in-Advance

Answer (score 0):

It's certainly possible, but depends a lot on your specific requirements.

Get the contents of the editor using [`editor.getData()`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-getData), then open a pop up window displaying that content - this should be relatively simple with JavaScript so I won't give any examples - you'll have to try it yourself first :). If a pop up is not something you want to use, maybe use an inline dialog, such as the ones that jQuery uses.

I would create the workflow so that the preview box has a save button inside it, forcing the user to preview before saving. If that's not acceptable, then create a separate button on your page to do the preview.